# SQL Selecting a View Inside an Inline Table Value Function Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a query that takes about 14 minutes to complete using an inline table valued function that selects from a view on a linked server. However, if this query is changed to remove the function and select directly from the query it completes in about 20 seconds.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetView](CompanyCharacters VARCHAR(4))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           [Some Rows]
    FROM   LinkedServer.Database.dbo.LinkedView
    WHERE  Co_char = RIGHT(REPLACE('0', 4) + 
                           CAST(@CompanyCharacters AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
)
```

Query that takes 14 minutes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Some Rows]
FROM   fn_GetSomeCompanyData() AS Comp
       JOIN CustomerData ON Comp.ID = CustomerData.CompID
       JOIN fn_GetView('MSF') AS gv ON gv.CompanyChar = Comp.CompanyChar
                                    AND gv.FirstName = Comp.FirstName
                                    AND gv.FirstName = Comp.FirstName
```

Changed Query that takes 20 seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Some Rows]
FROM   fn_GetSomeCompanyData() AS Comp
       JOIN CustomerData ON Comp.ID = CustomerData.CompID
       JOIN LinkedServer.Database.dbo.LinkedView AS gv ON gv.CompanyChar = Comp.CompanyChar
           AND gv.FirstName = Comp.FirstName
           AND gv.FirstName = Comp.FirstName
           AND gv.Co_char = RIGHT(REPLACE('0', 4) + 'MSF', 4)
WHERE [Some Data Filtering]
```

Anyone have any ideas why this behaves this way? Is there a best way to change the query so that it is fast but can also still keep the function?

Comment: There being inline TVF's and views has nothing to do with the perf problem because they are inlined as part of the optimization process. Their existence is removed in the earliest stages of query compilation. The *content* of them might be the reason.

Comment: You haven't completely integrated the TVF into your query - namely, your function has `SELECT DISTINCT`, but the 'changed query' does not.  Is this deliberate, or an oversight (you also aren't dealing replacing/casting characters, but that should be pretty much O(1) anyways)?  Are there any differences in results?  Simply cutting out the `DISTINCT` (or moving it to a different level) can result in huge performance differences, depending on what indices you have.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The DISTINCT part was actually an over site by me. It was supposed to be in there. I've updated it.

Comment: Can you post the query plan for both queries? Note that the second query still isn't equivalent to the first - the table-valued function includes the condition `Co_char = RIGHT(REPLACE('0', 4) + CAST(@CompanyCharacters AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)`.

Comment: @MarkBannister Unfortunately, I no longer have the specific data that was causing this slow down. It was only happening "randomly" and I was unable to ever reproduce the issue. I did however narrow it down to the TVF and once it was removed the issue was fixed. I looked at my updated query and added the other join filter. It was in my query I just hadn't added it here.